# Variable defined before calling of function does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a JS project and I am having the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * Need variables
     */
    var providers = $("#providers");
    var pagination = $("#pagination");
    var url = "/provider/provider_id_to_change/offers";
 
    /**
     * When a provider is selected
     */
    providers.change(function () {
 
        alert('Before Ajax: ' + url);

        var providerID = $(this).val();

        url = url.replace(/provider_id_to_change/, providerID);

        updateOffers(function(json) {});
    });


    
    function updateOffers(callback, page_to_visit) {

        page_to_visit = typeof(page_to_visit) != 'undefined' ? page_to_visit : 1;

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {page: page_to_visit}
        }).done(function(json){

            // Do something

   alert('After Ajax: ' + url);
   
            callback(json);

        });
    }
 
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="providers" style="width: 100%">
 <option value="prov_1">Provider 1</option>
 <option value="prov_2"> Provider 2</option>
 <option value="prov_3">Provider 3</option>
</select>
```

On the first ajax call the `url` variable which is by default `/provider/provider_id_to_change/offers` is changed successfully but after that all the ajax calls are not able to change the `url` as expected. 
To view the various changes applied to the url, in my code, there is one `alert` which displays the initial `url` before the ajax call and another `alert` which is displays after the ajax call.

A [JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/princelionelnzi/m8r5nd4v/) is available.

Kindly help me.

Comment: After you've changed it once, the "provider_id_to_change" part has been removed so there's nothing to replace anymore. You'll have to keep the original template in a separate variable that never changes (`var urlTemplate = "..."` and `url = urlTemplate.replace(...)`

Comment: you need to declare var url = "/provider/provider_id_to_change/offers"; in providers.change callback

Comment: I don't know how I come here but lol (_[proof](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/599/iK12wK.png)_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix. You need to keep the "template" URL the same so your string replace works every time you want to build a new URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * Need variables
     */
    var providers = $("#providers");
    var pagination = $("#pagination");
    var url = "/provider/provider_id_to_change/offers";
    var template_url = url; // SAVE URL TEMPLATE

    /**
     * When a provider is selected
     */
    providers.change(function () {
 
        alert('Before Ajax: ' + url);

        var providerID = $(this).val();

        url = template_url.replace(/provider_id_to_change/, providerID);

        updateOffers(function(json) {});
    });


    
    function updateOffers(callback, page_to_visit) {

        page_to_visit = typeof(page_to_visit) != 'undefined' ? page_to_visit : 1;

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {page: page_to_visit}
        }).done(function(json){

            // Do something

   alert('After Ajax: ' + url);
   
            callback(json);

        });
    }
 
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="providers" style="width: 100%">
 <option value="prov_1">Provider 1</option>
 <option value="prov_2"> Provider 2</option>
 <option value="prov_3">Provider 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue with the current code is that its looking for a specific string and replacing it with provider id. Since this string is replaces  in the first iteration itself in the next iteration the replace function will not do anything.

Once way to tackle this issue if the url path before provider id will always remain similar will be .split() and .join();

split the url by "/" and replace the value at the id index with provider id.

```
 providers.change(function() {

    alert('Before Ajax: ' + url);
    var providerID = $(this).val();
    var arr = url.split("/");
    arr[5] = providerID; // the id index
    url = arr.join("/");
    updateOffers(function(json) {});
  });
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/672nfo1t/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can - and should! - return Ajax requests from the functions that make them. Don't use "callback" semantics for jQuery Ajax requests anymore, that's outdated.

Secondly, avoid global variables, plain and simple. Try to write functions that do not depend on global state. This way, errors from unintentionally overwriting global state (like you did with the `url` variable) can be avoided.

Your code can be compressed into:

```
$(function() {
    $("#providers").change(function () {
        var providerId = $(this).val(),
            page = $("#pagination").val();

        getOffers(providerId, page).done(function (data) {
            // use data ...
        });
    });

    function getOffers(providerId, pageNum) {
        var url = "/provider/_/offers".replace("_", encodeURIComponent(providerId));
        return $.get(url, { page: pageNum || 1 });
    }
});
```

Thirdly, there is no reason to specify `dataType: 'json'` in an Ajax request. Make sure the server sends the proper Content-Type header and jQuery will do the right thing automatically.

Finally, you are not dealing with JSON. You are dealing with *data* (for example, an object, or an array). JSON purely is a transfer format. It stops being JSON after `JSON.parse()` has been called. Don't refer to it as JSON after this point in time.